# Using Text::Balanced to find strings enclosed in fat brackets {{..}} or [[..]]

Tags: regex, perl, brackets

I want to use `Text::Balanced` to extract some markup that uses `{{`...`}}` and `[[`...`]]` to markup its hyperlinks. For example:

```
This line contains {{path:to:mediafile|a hyperlink}} and [[path:to:page|another]] too.
```

`extract_bracketed()` is smart in the sense that it knows about bracket pairs --`{}`, `[]`, `<>`, `()`-- and looks for opening and closing brackets that are the same "shape". I can't use it, though, because it only works with single-character brackets.

I can use `extract_tagged()` to find one such type of "fat bracket" at a time, but it would be nice if it understood *several* symmetric bracket pairs. 
Is there a way to use Text::Balanced to extract strings that are enclosed by either `{{` and `}}`, or `[[` and `]]`, but not `{{` and `]]`, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they can't be nested, it can be done rather easily without Text::Balanced.

```
s/
   \{\{ ( (?:(?!\}\}).)* ) \}\}
   |
   \[\[ ( (?:(?!\]\]).)* ) \]\]
/
   defined($1) ? handle_curlies($1) : handle_squares($2)
/sexg
```

Comment: True, they can't be nested. This works nicely. Would you mind prefacing your answer by saying "Instead of using Text::Balanced, ..."?